# Sending long text from web form to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, this

I try to move my text analyzer from console to web form.

I have simple form like this:

```
<form action="/">
  <textarea name="str"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Generally I could have very long texts for analysis inside of textarea. When I submit the form I get the following from `thin`:

`Invalid request: Header longer than allowed`

So the question is what is the proper approach to send long texts to server? Uploading files or filling links to url are not the option unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the method of a form is GET, which has a limit on the number of characters allowed. (The limit depends on server and client, see for instance [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659995), which specifies that usually it is 8KB).

You should use instead a method POST, which has much larger limit, around 2GB.

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
  <textarea name="str"></textarea>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```